# Distribution of atan2 of normal r.v.'s

Tags: normal-distribution

Given $X\sim{\cal N}(\mu_X,\sigma^2_X)$, $Y\sim{\cal N}(\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$ I am looking for the p.d.f. of $\operatorname{atan2}(Y,X)$ where $\operatorname{atan2}()$ is the 4-quadrant arc tangent. Does this distribution have a name? Is there any literature about it?

Comment: A nicer--and very suggestive--alternative expression for this value is $\text{arg}(X+iY) = \operatorname{Im}(\log(X+iY))$, the polar angle of the complex number $X+iY$.

Comment: See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.4218/etrij.10.0210.0201

Comment: @whuber shouldn't that be $arg(x+i y)=-i*ln( (x+i y)/abs(x+iy) )$ as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Using_the_complex_logarithm ?

Comment: @bonanza Both expressions are correct. Writing $z=x+iy=\rho\exp(i\theta)$ ($\rho$ is real and nonnegative) it follows that $\log z=\log(\rho)+i\theta,$ whose imaginary part is $\operatorname{Im}(\log(z))=\theta.$ At the same time, $-i\log(z/|z|)=-i\log(\exp(i\theta))=-i^2\theta=\theta.$

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a simple expression for the pdf. If there were, then there would be a simple expression for the usual $\arctan$, and of the ratio between two (noncentered) normal distributions. The latter is studied in papers like Marsaglia (1965, [2006](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v16/i04/paper)) and Cedilnik et al ([2004](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pub/mz/mz1.1/cedilnik.pdf)).

Comment: (+1), allowing for one notable exception: when $\mu_X=\mu_Y=0$, the distribution obviously is uniform :-).

Comment: @whuber You probably want to insist on $\sigma_X^2 = \sigma_Y^2$ too in addition to $\mu_X = \mu_Y$.  But then, Douglas Zare was talking about _noncentered_ normal distributions...